# Advice about streaming live video to android/ios/pc

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming

i would like some advice about the best way to stream a only-video live stream from a server to:

- Android (>4.0 is ok)
- PC with web-browser
- iOS

I would like to keep latency as low as 1/2 second.

I can use:

- flash: works on PC but no iOS and no Android(works only on some tablets)
- HLS: not good because of latency
- proprietary library: it should work but i have to implement it everywhere
- RTSP: works only on Android

Any other way? Is a proprietary library the way to go?
I'm working on Linux but i'm mainly interested in "use this technology" and not "use this code".

Comment: You need,how can we do live video streaming in android??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you can try HTTP streaming of MP4/3gp formats using a web server. Both Android and iOS supports HTTP streaming. But you need to implement Progressive Download.

Please specify on which OS you want to implement your server.

For Windows - you can use following binary to relocate your moov atoms to the beginning of media file to enable them for progressive download
http://notboring.org/devblog/2009/07/qt-faststartexe-binary-for-windows/

Let us know your progress.

Comment: Sorry if i was not clear but it's live data. It's a never ending stream so i can't post-process a mp4 file.

Comment: When I run this binary, nothing happens. Just a command prompt window starts and disappears immediately. Can you please let me know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement FFmpeg Server for Live broadcast. It gives you various options. Enable/Disable options from its configuration file located at /etc/ffserver.conf

You can get detail documentation at
http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Rtsp might be the way to go , but that 1/2 second latency might be hard to get.
I guess for video only and if you don't buffer at all , this may work for ios anyway

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-tests

Android supports rtsp , but its not very good.

You can compile ffmpeg for android and write a simple player using OpenGL. I can't share the code because we did it for a client but its not to difficult.